# Use config value from MainActor class in other class

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm using Akka in my project and pull config values in my `MainActor` class. I want to be able to use `commit`, `version`, `author` `tag` inside of another file in order to build an avro response, but I can't just simply make MainActor the parent class of my Avro response interface. Is there a workaround?

My `MainActor` class

```
class MainActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with ConfigComponent with ExecutionContextComponent with DatabaseComponent with DefaultCustomerProfiles {

  override lazy val config: Config = context.system.settings.config

  override implicit lazy val executionContext: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher

  override val db: Database = Database.fromConfig(config.getConfig("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.database"))

  private val avroServer = context.watch {
    val binding = ReflectiveBinding[CustomerService.Async](customerProfileManager)

    val host = config.getString("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.avro.bindAddress")
    val port = config.getInt("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.avro.port")

    context.actorOf(AvroServer.socketServer(binding, host, port))
  }

  val commit = config.getString("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.version.commit")
  val author = config.getString("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.version.author")
  val tag =  config.getString("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.version.tag")
  val buildId = config.getString("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.version.buildId")

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    db.close()
    super.postStop()
  }

  //This toplevel actor does nothing by default
  override def receive: Receive = Actor.emptyBehavior

}
```

The class I want to pull values into

```
trait DefaultCustomerProfiles extends CustomerProfilesComponent {
  self: DatabaseComponent with ExecutionContextComponent =>

  lazy val customerProfileManager = new CustomerService.Async {

    import db.api._

    override def customerById(id: String): Future[AvroCustomer] = {
      db.run(Customers.byId(UUID.fromString(id)).result.headOption)
        .map(_.map(AvroConverters.toAvroCustomer).orNull)
    }

    override def customerByPhone(phoneNumber: String): Future[AvroCustomer] = {
      db.run(Customers.byPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).result.headOption)
        .map(_.map(AvroConverters.toAvroCustomer).orNull)
    }

    override def findOrCreate(phoneNumber: String, creationReason: String): Future[AvroCustomer] =  {
      db.run(Customers.findOrCreate(phoneNumber, creationReason)).map(AvroConverters.toAvroCustomer)
    }

    override def createEvent(customerId: String, eventType: String, version: Double, data: String, metadata: String): Future[AvroCustomerEvent] = {

      val action = CustomerEvents.create(
        UUID.fromString(customerId),
        eventType,
        Json.parse(data),
        version,
        Json.parse(metadata)
      )

      db.run(action).map(AvroConverters.toAvroEvent)
    }

    override def getVersion() : Version = {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another trait that defines the values, and mix it in with your MainActor and DefaultCustomerProfiles traits.

```
trait AnvroConfig {
   self: ConfigComponent

      val commit = config.getString("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.version.commit")
      val author = config.getString("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.version.author")
      val tag =  config.getString("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.version.tag")
      val buildId = config.getString("com.ojolabs.customer-profile.version.buildId")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really need is an [Akka Extension](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/extending-akka.html), which enables you to add features, like custom config, to your Akka system in an elegant way. This way, you would have access to those config values within all your actors from the actor system. As an example, check out this nice [blog post](http://tudorzgureanu.com/demystifying-akka-extensions/).

As for the other class from your example, you should pass them as parameters - it should be concerned with retrieving and parsing the config itself.